# Airflow templating for custom operator does not work in function argument

Tags: python, airflow, jinja2

I'm using the templating from Jinja in Airflow to parametrize an operator as described [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/custom-operator.html#templating).

I adapted the code to the following:

```py
class HelloOperator(BaseOperator):

    template_fields: Sequence[str] = ("name",)

    def f(self, name):
        'This function does nothing'
        return name

    def __init__(self, name: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = name
        self.name2 = self.f(name)
        self.name3 = self.f(self.name)

    def execute(self, context):
        message = f"Hello from {self.name}"
        print(message)
        message2 = f"Hello from {self.name2}"
        print(message2)
        message3 = f"Hello from {self.name3}"
        print(message3)
        return message
```

The output I get is the following:

```
[2022-12-07, 17:33:23 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Hello from task_id_1
[2022-12-07, 17:33:23 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Hello from {{ task_instance.task_id }}
[2022-12-07, 17:33:23 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Hello from {{ task_instance.task_id }}
```

Can somebody explain why the templating only works in the first case? The documentation says `Note that Jinja substitutes the operator attributes and not the args.` but how is this applicable in both the second and third case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you see is expected.
Templating happens during run time because only during run time you know how to replace the Jinja string with the actual value. Preparing a task to run involves many steps (templating is one of the steps).

The `__init__` function is executed before this (it's actually being executed every time the DAG is parsed) thus when you reach to the templating phase you have:

```
    self.name = {{ task_instance.task_id }}
    self.name2 = {{ task_instance.task_id }}
    self.name3 = {{ task_instance.task_id }}
```

but since you listed only `name` in `template_fields` then Jinja engine runs only on `name` which gives you:

```
    self.name = task_id_1
    self.name2 = {{ task_instance.task_id }}
    self.name3 = {{ task_instance.task_id }}
```

Comment: I see, so the clue is that the templating runs after the `__init__` constructor, then it makes sense.